If we only specify one sequence of partitions in the definition of Riemann-integral.
Update: This question differs from Question about Riemann integrability: do we need to specify that all Riemann sums converge to the same number in the definition? in the following way:
From what I see in that question(and answer by Thorgott) they assume that they have a sequence of partitions, and show that if the Riemann sum converges for all selctions it must be the same for another selection(with the same sequence of partitions). They do not show that if we have a given sequence of partitions that converges for all selections(for that sequence of parititons), than any other sequence of partitions with any selection also converges to the same number.
Start of original post:
I have this definition of a Riemann-sum:

Given a $f: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a partition
$\Pi=\{a=x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n=b\}$ and a selction $C=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\}$ where
$c_i\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$. We define the Riemann-sum
$$R(\Pi,C)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(c_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}).$$
Define $\lvert\Pi\rvert = \max \{x_i-x_{i-1}:1\le i\le n \}$

We define the Riemann-integral:

The function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable if
there is a real number $\alpha$ such that
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} R(\Pi_n,C_n)=\alpha,$$
for every sequence $\{\Pi_n,C_n\}$ of partitions and selctions
such that $\lvert\Pi_n\rvert \rightarrow 0$. The value $\alpha$ is
then valled the Riemann-integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$.

My question is: Is the definition below sufficient?:

The function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable if
there exists a sequence of partitions $\{\Pi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty,$ and a real number $\alpha$, such that $\lvert \Pi_n \rvert \rightarrow 0$ and such that for any selection $C_n$ we have
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} R(\Pi_n,C_n)=\alpha,$$
for every sequence $\{C_n\}$. The value $\alpha$ is
then valled the Riemann-integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$.

Basically: If we get it to work for one sequence of partitions, does it then converge for all sequence of partitions where the norm goes to zero?

@CherryBlossom From what I see in that question(and answer) they assume that they have a sequence of partitions, and show that if the Riemann sum converges for all selctions it must be the same for another selection(with the same sequence of partitions). They do not show that if we have a given partition that converges for all selections(for that sequence of parititons), than any other sequence of partitions with any selection also converges to the same number. However, I do see that the result is stated in the question, but I would like to have it shown. Maybe a reference can be given.

@CherryBlossom I am wondering about what RRL writes in the comments to Thorgott.

@CherryBlossom Maybe the comment by Paramanand Singh solves it, I am not sure. I do not quite understand how one would do the details.

In my opinion the answer is yes. I assume that the sequence of partitions is given but the sequence of intermediate  points $C_n$ is arbitrary.

This question is not a duplicate of the question it is currently linked to. That question asks whether, for a given sequence of partitions, one has to insist that the Riemann sums converge to the same limit independent of the choice of sample points made in forming the Riemann sums or whether that follows "for free". The present question asks whether, to know a function $f$ is Riemann integrable, it suffices to show  there is a single sequence of partitions for which the associated Riemann sums for $f$ converge.

@krm2233 Thank you for pointing that out. I am just very glad you got to post your solution before the question was closed.

The answer is "yes" and in fact you do not even need to assume that $|\Pi_n| \to 0$.
For convenience, I will use the Darboux definition of integrability:
Definitions

A partition $\Pi$ of a closed interval $[a,b]$ is a finite subset of $[a,b]$ containing the endpoints, $\{a,b\}$. We write $\Pi$ as a strictly increasing sequence $[a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b]$, so that $\Pi$ decomposes $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals $[x_{i-1},x_i]$. The mesh $|\Pi|$ of $\Pi$, is defined to be $|\Pi|=\max\{|x_i-x_{i-1}|:1\leq i \leq n\}$.  A step function is a function $\phi\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ for which there exists a partition $\Pi=[a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b]$ of $[a,b]$ such that $\phi$ is constant on the open sub-intervals $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ given by the partition $\Pi$. Such a partition is said to be adapted to $\phi$. Let $\mathcal S([a,b])$ be the space of step functions defined on the interval $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb R$.

The integral of such a step function $\phi$ with adapted partition $\Pi$ is defined to be
$$
\mathcal I(\phi)=\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(\frac{1}{2}(x_{i-1}+x_i))(x_i-x_{i-1}).
$$
It is independent of the choice of adapted partition $\Pi$.

Given a bounded function $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ we set
$$
\mathcal L(f)=\sup\{\mathcal I(\phi): \phi \in \mathcal S([a,b]), \forall t \in [a,b], \phi(t)\leq f(t)\}
$$
and
$$
\mathcal U(f)= \inf\{\mathcal I(\psi): \psi \in \mathcal S([a,b]), \forall t \in [a,b], \psi(t)\geq f(t)\}.
$$
We say $f$ is (Darboux) integrable if $\mathcal L(f)=\mathcal U(f)$ and when this is the case we set $\int f = \mathcal L(f)=\mathcal U(f)$.

Given a bounded function $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ and a partition $\Pi=[a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b]$ of $[a,b]$ say $(c_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a set of sample points if $c_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ and let $s_f(\Pi,(c_i)) \in \mathcal S([a,b])$ be the step function taking the value $c_i$ in $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ and same value as $f$ at the partition points. The associated Riemann sum $\mathcal R(f,\Pi,(c_i))$ is then the integral of the step function $s(\Pi,(c_i))$, that is
$$
\mathcal R(f,\Pi,(c_i)): = \mathcal I(s_f(\Pi,(c_i)) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(c_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}).
$$


Proposition 1
If $(\Pi_m)_{m \geq 1}$ is a sequence of partitions, $\Pi_m = [a=x_0^m<\ldots<x_{n_m}^m = b]$ such that for any choice of sample points $(c^m_i)$ (where $c^m_i \in (x^m_{i-1},x^m_i)$) we have
$$
\mathcal R(f,\Pi_m,(c^m_i)) = \sum f(c^m_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}) \to \alpha \text{ as } m \to \infty,
$$
then $f$ is integrable with $\int f=\alpha$.
Proof:
Fix any $\epsilon>0$. For the partition $\Pi_m$ choose $c^m_i\in [x^m_{i-1},x^m_i]$ such that $\sup\{f(x): x\in [x^m_{i-1},x^m_i]-\epsilon < f(c^m_i)$ and let $\psi_m$ be the step function whose value on $(x^m_{i-1},x^m_i)$ is $f(c^m_i)+\epsilon$ and whose value on $x^m_i$ is $f(x^m_i)$. Then for all $t \in [a,b]$ we have $f(t)\leq \psi_m(t)$ and
$$
\mathcal I(\psi_m) = \mathcal R(f,\Pi_m,(c^m_i))+\epsilon(b-a)
$$
Letting $m \to \infty$ we see that $\mathcal U(f)\leq \alpha +\epsilon(b-a)$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\mathcal U(f)\leq \alpha$.
Similarly, we can show that $\mathcal L(f)\geq \alpha$ and hence $\int f= \alpha$ as claimed. $\hspace{20mm}\square$
A variant of the above Proposition is that $f$ is integrable if there is a sequence of partition $(\Pi_m)_{m \geq 1}$ for which, $\lim_{m \to \infty} \mathcal R(f,\Pi_m,(c^m_i))$ exists for any choice of sample points for the $\Pi_m$. The equivalence of the two statements is shown in the answer to this question.
Now I have cheated to some extent, in that I have shown that the condition that the existence of a sequence of partitions $(\Pi_m)$ with the asserted property implies that $f$ is Darboux integrable, not Riemann integrable. Thus to make the argument complete, I need to show that Darboux integrability implies Riemann integrability.
Proposition 2
Suppose that $f\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a bounded function and that $f$ is (Darboux) integrable. Then for any sequence of partitions $(\Pi_m)_{m \geq 1}$ of $[a,b]$ satisfying $|\Pi_m|\to 0$ as $m\to \infty$ and any choice of tags $(c^m_i)$ we have
$$
\mathcal I(s_f(\Pi_m,(c^m_i)))\to \int f
$$
as $m\to \infty$.
Proof:
Let $M>0$ be such that $|f(t)|<M$ and fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is integrable there are step functions $\phi$ and $\psi$ with $\phi(t)\leq f(t)\leq \psi(t)$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ and
$$
\int f-\epsilon < \mathcal I(\phi)\leq \int f\leq \mathcal I(\psi) < \int f+\epsilon
$$
and clearly we may assume that $-M\leq \phi<\psi<M$.
Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ adapted to $\phi$ and $\psi$, so that if $P=[a=p_0<\ldots<p_k=b]$ then $\phi$ and $\psi$ are constant on the intervals $(p_{i-1},p_i)$. Since $|\Pi_m|\to 0$ as $m \to \infty$, there is an $N>0$ such that for all $m \geq N$ we have $|\Pi_m|<\frac{1}{2}\min\{|p_i-p_{i-1}|:1\leq i\leq k\}$.
It follows that if $(c^m_i)$ is a tagging of $\Pi_m$ where $m\geq N$, then at most $k$ intervals $[x^m_{i-1},x^m_i]$ associated to the partition $\Pi_m$ which intersect two intervals $[p_{j-1},p_j]$, $[p_j,p_{j+1}]$ associated to the partition $P$. Call these intervals special. Since $f\leq \psi$ we have $s_f(\Pi_m,(c^m_i))\leq \psi$ on the non-special intervals of $\Pi_m$, while on the special intervals we have $|\psi-s_f(\Pi_m,(c^m_i))|\leq 2M$, hence
$$
\mathcal I(\psi-s_f(\Pi_m,(c^m_i)))\geq \sum_{[x_{i-1},x_i] \text{ special}}-2M(x_i-x_{i-1}) \leq -2M|\Pi_m|k
$$
Similarly we have
$$
\mathcal I(s_f(\Pi_m,(c^m_i))-\phi)\geq -2M|\Pi_m|k.
$$
But then since $\mathcal I(\phi) >\int f -\epsilon$ and $\mathcal I(\psi)<\int f+\epsilon$ it follows that
$$
\int f -2M|\Pi_m|k -\epsilon < \mathcal I(s_f(\Pi_m,(c_i^m)))< \int f +2M|\Pi_m|k +\epsilon
$$
But $|\Pi_m|\to 0$ as $m \to \infty$, hence we may find an $N_\epsilon>0$ such that $2Mk\|\Pi_m|<\epsilon$ for all $m \geq N_{\epsilon}$. Setting $N_1 = \max\{N,N_{\epsilon}\}$ it follows that for $m \geq N_1$ we have
$\mathcal I(s_f(\Pi_m,(c^m_i))\in (\int f-2\epsilon, \int f+2\epsilon)$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary it follows that $\mathcal R(f,\Pi_m,(c^m_i)) = \mathcal I(s_f(\Pi_m,(c^m_i))) \to \int f$ as required.
$\hspace{20mm}\square$
Finally, although Proposition 1 shows that the definition the OP asks about is correct, it is probably better thought of as a criterion for integrability rather than the definition of integrability, because either the Darboux or Riemann definition is much more robust -- once you know a function is integrable, then you can compute (or at least estimate) the integral using any sequence of partitions that is convenient. Since in practice one usually establishes that a function $f$ is integrable from quite general results -- e.g. because it is continuous -- the more robust formulations of the property of being integrable are usually

Your theorem doesn't require the mesh/norm to tend to zero, but instead asks for a stronger condition that not only all the Riemann sums converge, but converge to the same number. For non-integrable functions one can always find a sequence of partitions that the Riemann sums converge but not to same number if we vary the tags. The arbitrary nature of tags is essentially what captures the infimum / supremum used in Darboux definition.

Great answer and +1

@ParamanandSingh if all possible Riemann sums converge then they must converge to the same limit -- take the your examples of two Riemann sums converging to different limits and use them as the even and odd terms of a new sequence. The new sequence will not converge, so not all Riemann sums -- see the question linked in my post just after the proof of Proposition 1.

Thanks for correcting me.

I prefer phrasing the condition for a function to be Riemann integrable without sequences to be honest -- i.e. f is integrable if there is a number $\alpha$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if the mesh of a partition $\mathcal P$ is less than $\delta$ then any Riemann sum obtained from $\mathcal P$ is within $\epsilon$ of $\alpha$.
